# Remove object from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I have a PhoneGap + Onsen UI + AngularJS app in the works, where I have a list in the view, where the items will be fetched from the controllers variable.

I want to be able to remove items from this list, by clicking on them.

The list looks like this:

```
<ons-list> 
    <ons-list-item  modifier="tappable" class="item" ng-repeat="citem in completeditems" ng-click="delete(citem)">
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col>
                <div class="titlediv">
                    <header>
                        <span class="item-title">{{citem.name}}</span>
                    </header>
                </div>
                <div class="item-dates">
                    <span class="item-start">{{citem.start}}</span>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
    </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

The completeditems object in the $scope looks like this:

```
var completeditemname = "item" + i;
$scope.completeditems[completeditemname] = {
    id : "ID",
    name : "Name for it",
    start: "Start date"
}
```

Tried the following method, but it didn't work out:

```
$scope.delete = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.completeditems.indexOf(item);
    $scope.completeditems.splice(index,1);
    //$scope.completeditems.remove(item); //tried this aswell
    $scope.$apply() //i need this to update the view
}
```

Comment: does `var index = $scope.completeditems.indexOf(item);` find the item ? Does it return the correct index ? you might need to serach the collection by an id or something.

Comment: var index = $scope.completeditems.indexOf(item); will not find the item

Comment: then you need to find the item index in the collection the old fashioned way ( iterate in a for ). The issue is that the item is getting modified and the reference is changed ...

Comment: you should create new array for saving ids of completedItems  and save objects id. Then you can check with id( `idArray.indexOf(item.id)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the `$scope.$apply()` invocation. As you are making alterations to scope variables the digest cycle will be triggered anyhow and you will be encountering an error because of this I believe.

**UPDATED::** You're working with an actual object by the looks of it so I've updated the code in the plunker to help you out. It means altering the `ng-repeat` to use both key and value.

Here is a simple plunkr showing a basic example of what you are trying to do with a one liner in the delete function [http://plnkr.co/edit/NtQD...](http://plnkr.co/edit/ie9LzAVqiQiGZGVtLmpO?p=preview).

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in ctrl.items track by key">
      <li ng-click="ctrl.delete(key)">{{value}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', [
  '$scope',
  function($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.items  = {
      item1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'a'
      },
      item2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'b'
      },
      item3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'c'
      }
    };
    self.delete = function(key) {
      delete self.items[key];
    };
  }
]);
```

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: My "items" scope variable is not an array.

Comment: I've updated it to work how I think you need it to. It's working on a standard object that is being dynamically created so needs the `ng-repeat` syntax updating. Then you can just delete the key from the object on click. Hope I've got this right for you.

Comment: In your case, your delete function would do something like `delete $scope.completedItems[key]`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much jh3y!

Answer (score 0):

$scope.$apply() should only be used when changes are coming in from outside the Angular framework. Since your delete() function is being called from an ng-click, it is already being managed by Angular and calling $apply() will raise a "$digest is already in progress" error (check your browser console). Removing that call will most likely get your code working.

Comment: I removed it and it's still not working. Check my $scope.items object. I guess it's not an array, but some collection of objects.